# How to declare array in object and store with encode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a class Ticket. In that ticket I want a mutable array of NSStrings
i.e. in ticket.h

```
@interface Ticket : NSObject
@property NSString *ticketName;
@property NSMutableArray *games;
```

However Objective C doesn't allow me to do this. What am I supposed to do to have an array inside an object?

I then want to store that array using `encodeWithCoder` in the implementation of the object

Comment: Did you missing @property (nonatomic,strong) ?

Comment: I think you have a syntax problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like i said you might have a syntax problem, there is no reason why Objective-c won't allow you to add an `NSMutableArray` into your custom objects, try this:

```
    @interface MyObject : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;

    //
    // .. other properties
    //

    @end
```

and in the implementation

```
@implementation MyObject

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.myMutableArray addObject:@"myString1"];
  [self.myMutableArray addObject:@"myString2"];
  [self.myMutableArray addObject:@"myString3"];
}
```

Comment: Wow!  I found other web articles that said it couldn't be done and had been avoiding it for ages.  Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Glad to help my friend!